# Последовательное возведение чисел в куб их их дальнейшее сложение

Tags: c#

К примеру есть число 153
и следующий код

```
        int a = 153;
        string a1 = Convert.ToString(a);
        char[] ch = a1.ToCharArray();
        int sss =Convert.ToInt32( Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32( ch[0]),3)+Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(ch[1]), 3)+Math.Pow(Convert.ToInt32(ch[2]), 3));
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(sss));
```

По идее в MessageBox должно быть число 153,но там 399177
Где ошибка?

Comment: Отладчик используйте...

Comment: В том, что возводятся в степень не 1, 5 и 3 как числа, а коды char '1', '5' и '3'

Comment: [Convert.ToInt32(char ch)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ww9t2871) возвращает код символа из таблицы Unicode. Чтобы получить число используйте [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h1hf19)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы,всё понял.Как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: @deced, просто напишите свой ответ